# Selenium code halts mid-execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver

while trying to run a script, the execution stops at random points and there is no error on Console as well. In other words, the script hangs neither proceeding as per the steps nor gives any error on the console. Any idea where I could be going wrong?

I have tried reinstalling JRE, Selenium server (different versions even).

I am using Selenium v2.47.1 with Firefox v38.2.1

Comment: Do you have sample code with sample points that it fails in? My suggestion is to use System.out.println("Error fails after this step + stepname");

Comment: The failure point is not constant. And the interesting thing is that I do not get any error on the console. It is just as if the program has entered an infinite loop.

Comment: You'll have to share some code to give an idea of what's happening. Sounds like a really long wait somewhere in the code to be honest. Could be that you're just not waiting long enough for it to throw an exception in the console.

Comment: I am doing a simple driver.get() followed by element.click(). Nothing fancy and there is wait but no longer than 60 seconds. However, the issue is that even after 10 minutes, the code does not execute and does not even throw any exceptions. And this issue has been observed after the latest build.

Comment: I found out that the group policies of my organization had put restrictions on the browser which caused this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the group policies of my organization had put restrictions on the browser which caused this issue